# How do I speed up iterations for web crawling ids-nokogiri/ruby

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri

What I want to do is iterate through all possible product pages given a 10 digit numerical id

an example of the page I would like to scrape is somewebsite.com/product?productid=10000000000

The scraper would go to the page see if a tag exists to see if it is a product page and then log the url if it is or move on to the next page if it is not.

doing iterations 1 by 1 (productid = large number++)is too slow and from looking at some sample product ids it seems like numbers without patterns such as(121212121212) are more likely I wanted to ask what would be a way to iterate through these pages in a more reasonable amount of time. I am doing this in ruby with nokogiri right now.

Comment: We need to see your current code for iterating, stripped down to just the bare code handling that part. We also need a better understanding of the ids.

Comment: Use the curb gem for downloading all the pages and then parse them. https://github.com/taf2/curb

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through that number of product IDs is a horrible way to treat a target site, and odds are good you'd get banned because it's not likely their products are sequentially numbered. In other words, you would get a lot of missing page responses, which will be logged, and if their web-development team is decent they'll get a list of those along with the requesting IP.

Instead, be smart and find a page that lists all their products, parse out that list, then walk it. If there isn't a single page containing them, but many, then start at the first and walk them all until you've reached the last one. Aggregate the product IDs into an array, or process them as you read each page.

Also, be very gentle and kind to their site by sleeping between iterations. Failing to do that can also get you banned because requesting thousands of pages, one immediately after another, will drive up their host's CPU, network usage, which again will alert them that you are spidering their site and negatively impacting their ability to serve normal customers.

Finally, if you really want to do things the right way, your first connection to the site should request their "robots.txt" file. Process it, and use those directives in your code. That file is put there to help robots/spiders/scrapers do the right thing and not unfairly antagonize the site or web-admins of the site. Failing to do that is a sure path to being banned. More information is available at "[The Web Robots Pages](http://www.robotstxt.org)" and "[Robots exclusion standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)".